# Why MQTT sends more packets than TCP?

Tags: mqtt, iot

I have run some traffic from one server to another. In the first scenario, the packets were sent through TCP protocol. In the another scenario, the packets were sent through MQTT protocol (which also runs over TCP). Through the MQTT exchange scenario, the packets sent from server1 to server2 are 3 times more than the packets sent from servier1 to server2 when I used just the TCP.

Comment: how does your question relate to IoT? Not everything that touches networks, connections or servers relates to IoT. I dont see any relation. If there' nothing more to it, please remove IoT tag.

Comment: also, since you admit that this mqtt implementation runs over tcp, I'd expect that number of packets sent will be at least the same, or higher, than communication using direct tcp. Why is it 3 times more? I dont know. Maybe it's just the size of extra wrapping, or maybe that's some subscribe/unsubscribe messages. Who knows. It is your application, and you said nothing about how it runs or what is sent over the wire. You have not even said what is the concept or scheme behind networking in your application. How do we guess? In meantime, maybe just grab Wireshark and see it for youself?

Comment: You need to supply WAY more information to get a proper answer. How big is the payload, what QOS did you use, what was the topic you published to, what did you set the keepalive value to?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl MQTT is considered a IoT protocol so it is a reasonable tag

Comment: MQTT has its own handshake when connecting - did you count those, or did you only count MQTT messages with user payload ?  Does your MQTT library disable Nagle algorithm to deliver data quicker, possibly at the expense of sending more TCP segments? Does your custom protocol, running on top of TCP send application acks of the application data, like MQTT does ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the higher-level protocols (above TCP).
The MQTT protocol sends PUBACK for QOS 1, so would double the number of packets from just a send of the payload.
Your protocol is secret, so we cannot comment on it.
A Wireshark PCAP would allow you to diagnose the imbalance.